# Running SolrJ on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, solr, solrj

I'm trying to setup a SolrJ using Eclipse by following the example in http://lucidworks.com/blog/indexing-with-solrj/

However, when I try to run the code using Run As -> Java Application, it came back with an error saying that 'Selection does not contain a main type'. But I see that that there's a main method in the code, and it has already been added to my code in Eclipse. My eclipse has got the same code as the example, except for the path name and document name.

Is there any thing required that I missed out in order for the code to run successfully in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so that means in alternative:

A) your're doing "run as -->> Java application" from the wrong class. Open then class that contains the main, right click on that and choos "Runs as Java Application"

B) your main method has a wrong signature (and therefore is not a valid main method)

  -

Comment: I think the problem was with B). I was running the "Run As -> Java Application" from the particular class which I'm writing. Now I've created a new Java project and import the required Solr jars into the project, instead of using the same project as the rest of the Solr codes, and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you jave no compilation errors, check the "Builds automatically" flag in Eclipse or manually build the project. Then, you can retry

Comment: There's no compilation errors in my java, and the "Build automatically" flag has already been set. But I'm still getting the same error message when I run the code.